# Local Binary Patterns original code and references in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, lbph-algorithm

I'm founding lots of implementations of Local Binary Patterns with matlab and i am a little confusing about them.

Wikipedia explains how the [basic LBP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) works:

```
1- Divide the examined window into cells (e.g. 16x16 pixels for each cell).
2- For each pixel in a cell, compare the pixel to each of its 8 neighbors (on its left-top, left-middle, left-bottom, right-top, etc.). Follow the pixels along a circle, i.e. clockwise or counter-clockwise.
3- Where the center pixel's value is greater than the neighbor's value, write "1". Otherwise, write "0". This gives an 8-digit binary number (which is usually converted to decimal for convenience).
4- Compute the histogram, over the cell, of the frequency of each "number" occurring (i.e., each combination of which pixels are smaller and which are greater than the center).
5- Optionally normalize the histogram.
6- Concatenate (normalized) histograms of all cells. This gives the feature vector for the window.
```

looking at this algorithm I can conclude that each LBP feature vector will have num_cels*256 dimensions, where num_cels is the number of 16x16 pixels cells of images. Each cell will have 256 possible values (0 to 255) and so the feature vector size can vary a lot.

But, looking at some LBP implementations, the [VLFEAT_LBP](http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_lbp.html) returns a matrix instead of a feature vector. In [this implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36484-local-binary-patterns) LBP is returned as a 256 feature vector which I think (not sure) is the sum of all histograms of all cells. All I want to know is: which is the classic LBP explanation and matlab source code.

Comment: Canonical = [Ojala, et al.](http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/Downloads/LBPMatlab).

Comment: @chappjc Thank you so much for your information. What I saw in the source code is that the information from wikipedia (step 6) is not true. The resulting image for LBP is, in each pixel, a 8 bit binary number which represents how the pixel behaves according to its neighbors. This binary number converted to decimal can have the maximum value 255 and minimum value 0. After each pixel is represented this way a histogram with 256 bins is constructed. The concatenation of histograms in each cell is not done. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% clc;    % Clear the command window.
% close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
% imtool close all;  % Close all imtool figures.
% clear;  % Erase all existing variables.
% workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
% fontSize = 20;
% % Read in a standard MATLAB gray scale demo image.
% folder = fullfile(matlabroot, '\toolbox\images\imdemos');
% baseFileName = 'cameraman.tif';
% % Get the full filename, with path prepended.
% fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
% if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
%   % Didn't find it there.  Check the search path for it.
%   fullFileName = baseFileName; % No path this time.
%   if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
%       % Still didn't find it.  Alert user.
%       errorMessage = sprintf('Error: %s does not exist.', fullFileName);
%       uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
%       return;
%   end
% end
grayImage = imread('fig.jpg');
% Get the dimensions of the image.  numberOfColorBands should be = 1.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);

% Display the original gray scale image.
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(grayImage, []);
%title('Original Grayscale Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); 
set(gcf,'name','Image Analysis Demo','numbertitle','off') 
% Let's compute and display the histogram.
[pixelCount grayLevels] = imhist(grayImage);
subplot(2, 2, 2); 
bar(pixelCount);
%title('Histogram of original image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
xlim([0 grayLevels(end)]); % Scale x axis manually.
% Preallocate/instantiate array for the local binary pattern.
localBinaryPatternImage = zeros(size(grayImage));
for row = 2 : rows - 1   
    for col = 2 : columns - 1    
        centerPixel = grayImage(row, col);
        pixel7=grayImage(row-1, col-1) > centerPixel;  
        pixel6=grayImage(row-1, col) > centerPixel;   
        pixel5=grayImage(row-1, col+1) > centerPixel;  
        pixel4=grayImage(row, col+1) > centerPixel;     
        pixel3=grayImage(row+1, col+1) > centerPixel;    
        pixel2=grayImage(row+1, col) > centerPixel;      
        pixel1=grayImage(row+1, col-1) > centerPixel;     
        pixel0=grayImage(row, col-1) > centerPixel;       
        localBinaryPatternImage(row, col) = uint8(...
            pixel7 * 2^7 + pixel6 * 2^6 + ...
            pixel5 * 2^5 + pixel4 * 2^4 + ...
            pixel3 * 2^3 + pixel2 * 2^2 + ...
            pixel1 * 2 + pixel0);
    end  
end 
subplot(2,2,3);
imshow(localBinaryPatternImage, []);
%title('Local Binary Pattern', 'FontSize', fontSize);
subplot(2,2,4);
[pixelCounts, GLs] = imhist(uint8(localBinaryPatternImage));
bar(GLs, pixelCounts);
%title('Histogram of Local Binary Pattern', 'FontSize', fontSize);
```