# How to Divide an image into 3x3 blocks in MATLAB and compute histogram for each block

Tags: matlab, histogram, block, divide, lbph-algorithm

I am working on "Machine Detection of Hand-over-Face Gestures" using LBP. I just converted an RGB Image to LBP image using [this Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161194/local-binary-patters-original-code-and-references-in-matlab). Next Step of my task is to divide LBP image into 3x3 and display histogram for each block to detect the hand gesture position as shown in the following Fig:

[Images along with their histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wjB3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try [mat2cell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html). Assuming your matrix is a `NXN` square matrix:

```
matSize = size(inputMatrix,1);
subMatrix = mat2cell(inputMatrix,3*ones(1,matSize/3),3*ones(1,matSize/3));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually I am at beginner  level of MATLAB. would like to explain it with complete code. Thank you

Comment: @NisaSoomro You should try to figure it out by yourself. Use [`hist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) function for histogram plot of your data. `inputMatrix` is you LBP image matrix, and `subMatrix` is a cell consisting of `3X3` blocks.